# Can findContour in OpenCV work like bwlabel in Matlab?

Tags: c++, image, matlab, opencv

Some people in this Q & A site suggested I use findContour to imitate what bwlabel in Matlab. But I am not sure because I think a contour is closed shape of detected edges and element from bwlabel is a connected shape. I guess they might be logically the same. What about them in practice? Are they really same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either of these two library....[cvBlobslib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib)  or [cvblob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/)...you will get many features about the connected components such as size and contour and ellipticity and bounding box...you can filter blobs and add togethar 2 or more blobs...try it..under the hood algo of bwlabel is a two scan connected component where as cvblob or cvBlobslib is a one scan algo...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yeah, I was afraid that someone would say so but I guess I have no choice. Do you have any idea how they (cvBlobLib and cbBlob) differ?

Comment: no they dont differ as per the basic algorithm for labelling the connected components are concerned...some one or two functions mite be extra here and there...i havent used cvblob...i have used cvblobslib...u can use either..

Answer (score 1):

`bwlabel` will give you the image connected components, i.e. different label for different connected objects in a background.

Probably what you mean is the combination of [im2bw](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html) and [imcontours](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcontour.html) provides, i.e. a combination of binarizing the image and trivially finding the single contour (boundaries) per retained object on the output.

Consider the following example:

```
I = imread('coins.png'); % grayscale
level = graythresh(I); % find thershold
BW = im2bw(I, level); % threshold image
imcontour(BW, 1); % plot single contour
```

[image]

For a grayscale image you can increase the number of requested contours, though [findContours](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours)  operates on binary images.

Comment: No, I meant bwlabel. So you agree that bwlabel and findContour are different? As rotating_image said, I think I go with a blob library. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, they are different and that's what I tried to clarify. The output of `findContours` will not give you connected components. Both will operate on binary images, one will find boundaries of all/every component, the other will separate based on connectivity.

Comment: Hmm...I just looked into cvBlob source code and found that it is actually find contours in the process. Interesting.

Comment: the cvblob uses this algorithm..."A linear-time component labeling algorithm using contour tracing technique", F.Chang et al.....that is how it finds connected components...so it need to find contours..

Answer (score 0):

I found [an exact article about this.](http://lamuerte.soup.io/post/193984474/Speed-comparison-cvBlob-vs-OpenCV-s-cv) Quick answer is "Yeah, their eventual output will be the same." So I might go with findContour after all considering cvBlob still using old C-style API and having its own implementation of finding contours.